# React-router, Redux, server-side rendering : Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm a newbie in server-side rendering. My stack is mainly: Webpack, React, React-Router, Redux, Babel. The creation of bundle works great. But when I open my browser I get this error :

> Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here my server.js :

```
// create htmlTemplate to serve to client
const htmlTemplate = (template, initialState) => { 
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
     <title>Universal Reacl</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
   </head>
   <body><div id="root">${template}</div>
   <script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(initialState)}</script>
   <script src="./bundle.js" defer></script>

   </body>
 </html>
 `
}

// listen client request => release server file 
app.use((req,res) => { 



    // create store with appReducer inside
    const store=configureStore();

  const branch = matchRoutes(routes, req.url);
  const promises = branch.map(({route}) => {
    let fetchData = route.component.fetchData;
    return fetchData instanceof Function ? fetchData(store) : Promise.resolve(null)
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    let context = {};
    const template = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          {renderRoutes(routes)}
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
   if(context.status === 404) {
          res.status(404);
   }


            // set initial component _ state 
            const initialState=store.getState() 

            // set html server's page 
            const HTML=htmlTemplate(template, initialState);

            res.end(HTML);
        });
})

export default app;
```

here my client.js :

```
// view 
import React from 'react';
import {hydrate} from "react-dom" ;

// router 
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import  {AppRoute}  from "../app/Router";

// data flow
import {configureStore} from "../app/store";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const history = createMemoryHistory();

let initialState=window.__INITIAL_STATE__; 

const store = configureStore(initialState); 

const root=document.getElementById('root')


hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>    
    {() =>
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <AppRoute/>
    </BrowserRouter>
    }
    </Provider>,
    root
)
```

It seems to  me all is great, fetches data, push routes and all if someone has a hint on what was going wrong, would be great,

Thanks

Comment: I have found what was wrong, it that I imported browser history on Node. To be imported createBrowserHistory need a DOM. The error message is definitely very poor.

Comment: Please, pay attention to indentation, better even use `Prettier`